# Redirect multiple domains on one server to their respective https://www. target

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, dns, apache2

I have a dated (pre 2015) Wordpress Multisite set up with a multi-domain SAN SSL installed, for now I need to redirect multiple domains on one server to their respective https://www. target.

For example I have www.domain1.co.uk, www.domain2.co.uk, www.domain3.co.uk, each of these domains are reachable via https://www.  however they are still also reachable by http://www. and they currently do not redirect to https://www.

Can you help with what I should be needing to put into either the server configuration file, or the .htaccess file? I require the end user to reach the end website like https://www.domain1.co.uk irrespective of how they type the http protocol in the address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the redirection at the virtual host level. Just like below

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName mysite.example.com
       Redirect permanent / https://mysite.example.com/
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
       ServerName mysite.example.com
       DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
       SSLEngine On
    # etc...
    </VirtualHost>
```